# How to encode a url segment in Angular 7 in the Template for an image url

Tags: html, angular, urlencode

I have the following bit of code which is my attempt at encoding the url:

```
<img src="{{ '/assets/images/animals/' + (data.animal.image | encodeURIComponent) }}" alt="" class="animal" />
```

I'm getting the error:

```
The pipe 'encodeURIComponent' could not be found
```

I'm assuming there is no such pipe, or I should be importing something somewhere.

What is the right way of doing this, preferably all in the template?

As requested, here is a sample of the data

```
data = { "animal" : { id: 1; image:"dog.png"; } }
```

Comment: why do you need to use a uri encoder if I may ask?

Comment: I'm getting the data from a file, and I'd like to make sure it is properly encoded before sending to the server

Comment: you could just do it like this <img src="/assets/images/animal/?query={{data.animal.image}}">

Comment: Feel free to add an answer? I am accessing a static resource on the server, so I don't think the query= syntax will produce the correct url?

Comment: well first of all you are missing the query parameter I used a fake 'query=' if you need to encode a complex file name then you would do that on the backend before you get the variable and put it in could you show the ts code

Comment: well at the moment the way it is on your example it always references a relative path to your project so if the image is not in the root of your project you will need to supply the full absolute path and concat the variable data

Comment: I added the sample data to show what is inside the data object. The typescript is trivial, just exposing the data object that is imported

Comment: <img src="/assets/images/animal/?animal={{data.animal.image}}">

Comment: but the question is are you serving this image from your route folder because if you are then there is no url encoding needed its just a path <img src="/assets/images/animal/{{data.animal.image}}">

Comment: url encoding is mostly used for making requests to a server so like a get request to a route that will hit a db for an image, if its just a link to a path there is no url encoding. It would just be the path to your directory (dist) and the assets folder that gets bundled when you build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few different options:

1. This method uses CSS and sets the image as a background so it resize better.

   `<div [style.backgroundImage]="'url('+ image +')'" class="image"></div>`
2. Use Angular sanitizer to make sure that the url does not contain dangerous script https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer
3. Call a function to calculate the url, then it can run the encode you want.
   `<img [src]="getImageUrl(data.animal.image)" />`